# Typescript - Duplicate identifier error - const x: ({ y: string, z: string }) => string;

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Why does the following code mark `string`s in the parameters with an error `Duplicate identifier 'string'.(2300)`?

```js
const append: ({ first: string, second: string }) => string = ({ first, second }) => first + second;

console.log(append({ first: "a", second: "b" }));
```

It compiles and runs correctly, though.

### Reproduction

- Paste the code here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play
- You'll find the error highlighted.
- If you click on "Run", it'll log `ab` correctly, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not defining the type correctly, you want

```
const append: (input: { first: string, second: string }) => string = ({ first, second }) => first + second;
```

In a more explicit entry, this is the same as:

```
interface Input {
    first: string;
    second: string;
}

interface Append {
    (input: Input): string;
}

const append: Append = ({first, second}) => {
    return first + second;
}
```